# Colour each graph differently

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, color, parametric-functions

I have a `Manipulate` function, which allows me to compile plots on a single plot (see below). I am trying to make each line on the compiled plot to be a different colour, however, Mathematica does not allow me to do this. What am I doing wrong?

In the code below, I have tried to ensure the first of the compiled plots is blue and the second is red, however, they both turn out red.

```
(* Constants *)

au = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "AstronomicalUnit"], "Meters"]]; 
c = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"], "MetersPerSecond"]]; 
Qpr = 1; 
Lsun = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarLuminosity"], "Watts"]]; 
Rsun = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarRadius"], "Meters"]]; 
Msun = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "SolarMass"], "Kilograms"]]; 
G = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "GravitationalConstant"], ("Meters"^2*"Newtons")/"Kilograms"^2]]; 
year = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Years"], "Seconds"]]; 
Myr = year*10^6; 
Gyr = year*10^9; 
Mwd = 0.6*Msun; 
Cst = 1.27; 
U = 1*10^17; 

(* Functions *)

L[t_] := (3.26*Lsun*(Mwd/(0.6*Msun)))/(0.1 + t/Myr)^1.18; 
Roche[dens_] := (0.65*Cst*Rsun*(Mwd/(0.6*Msun))^(1/3))/(dens/3000)^3^(-1); 
Papsis[t_] := a[t]*(1 - e[t]); 

(* Radiative Drag *)

RDdadtRρa = -((3*L[t]*Qpr*(2 + 3*e[t]^2))/(c^2*(16*Pi*ρ*Rast*a[t]*(1 - e[t]^2)^(3/2)))); 
RDdedtRρa = -((15*L[t]*e[t])/(c^2*(32*Pi*Rast*ρ*a[t]^2*Sqrt[1 - e[t]^2]))); 

RDsolRρa = 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {Derivative[1][a][t] == RDdadtRρa, 
     Derivative[1][e][t] == RDdedtRρa, 
     a[0] == a0, e[0] == 0.3
    }, {a, e}, {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, {Rast, ρ, a0}]; 

fRDticks = {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1/Myr}], Automatic}}; 

Manipulate[
  Column[{
    Style["Radiative Drag Working Plot", Bold], 
    Plot[
      fun[func, t]/scale[func], {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, 
      FrameTicks -> fRDticks, 
      Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, InfiniteLine[{{0, Roche[ρ]}, {10, Roche[ρ]}}]}, 
      PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.01]]}
    ],
    Style["Compiled Plot", Bold], 
    If[comp === {}, 
      Plot[fun[func, t]/scale[func], {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, FrameTicks -> fRDticks, Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, InfiniteLine[{{0, Roche[ρ]}, {10, Roche[ρ]}}]}, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.01]]}], 
      Plot[comp/scale[func], {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, FrameTicks -> fRDticks, Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, InfiniteLine[{{0, Roche[ρ]}, {10, Roche[ρ]}}]}, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.01]], Directive[Red, Thickness[0.01]]}]
    ]
  }], 
  {{func, 1}, {1 -> "a", 2 -> "e", 3 -> "q"}}, 
  {{Rast, 0.005}, 0.0001, 0.1, 0.001, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{ρ, 3000}, 1000, 7000, 50, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  {{a0, 10, "a0 (au)"}, 1, 20, 0.2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  Button["Append", AppendTo[comp, fun[func, t]]], 
  Button["Reset", comp = {}], 
  TrackedSymbols -> {func, Rast, ρ, a0}, 
  Initialization :> {
     comp = {}, 
     fun[sel_, t_] := Switch[sel, 1, RDsolRρa[Rast, ρ, a0*au][[1]][t], 2, RDsolRρa[Rast, ρ, a0*au][[2]][t], 3, RDsolRρa[Rast, ρ, a0*au][[1]][t]*(1 - RDsolRρa[Rast, ρ, a0*au][[2]][t])], 
     scale[sel_] := Switch[sel, 1 | 3, au, 2, 1]
  }
]
```

Comment: Where did you get the code from? Your code formats the plots in red after you click on the Append button, according to the conditional plotting function you gave in your Manipulate.

Comment: @MarcoB I've been building the code up myself but I'm not familiar with formatting and colouring graphs in Mathematica

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thickness[0.01]]}` for the second plot. Here is the changes code:

```
fRDticks = {{Automatic, 
    Automatic}, {Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1/Myr}], Automatic}};

Manipulate[
 Column[{Style["Radiative Drag Working Plot", Bold], 
   Plot[fun[func, t]/scale[func], {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, 
    FrameTicks -> fRDticks, 
    Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, 
      InfiniteLine[{{0, Roche[\[Rho]]}, {10, Roche[\[Rho]]}}]}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.01]]}],
   Style["Compiled Plot", Bold],
   If[comp === {},
    
    Plot[fun[func, t]/scale[func], {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, 
     FrameTicks -> fRDticks, 
     Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, 
       InfiniteLine[{{0, Roche[\[Rho]]}, {10, Roche[\[Rho]]}}]}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thickness[0.01]]}],
    
    Plot[comp/scale[func], {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, FrameTicks -> fRDticks, 
     Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, 
       InfiniteLine[{{0, Roche[\[Rho]]}, {10, Roche[\[Rho]]}}]}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thickness[0.01]], 
       Directive[Red, Thickness[0.01]]}]
    ]}], {{func, 1}, {1 -> "a", 2 -> "e", 3 -> "q"}}, {{Rast, 0.005}, 
  0.0001, 0.1, 0.001, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{\[Rho], 3000}, 1000,
   7000, 50, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a0, 10, "a0 (au)"}, 1, 20, 
  0.2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 Button["Append", AppendTo[comp, fun[func, t]]], 
 Button["Reset", comp = {}], 
 TrackedSymbols -> {func, Rast, \[Rho], a0}, 
 Initialization :> {comp = {}, 
   fun[sel_, t_] := 
    Switch[sel, 1, RDsolR\[Rho]a[Rast, \[Rho], a0*au][[1]][t], 2, 
     RDsolR\[Rho]a[Rast, \[Rho], a0*au][[2]][t], 3, 
     RDsolR\[Rho]a[Rast, \[Rho], a0*au][[1]][
       t]*(1 - RDsolR\[Rho]a[Rast, \[Rho], a0*au][[2]][t])], 
   scale[sel_] := Switch[sel, 1 | 3, au, 2, 1]}]
```

[image]

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. When I specify a set of parameter values, and press `Append`, the graph is saved into the compiled plot. When I change the parameter values and `Append`, a second plot is added to the compiled plot. I want these plots to be in different colours.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend avoiding boilerplate repetitions. Since your plotting options for the two branches of your `If` are the same, and only the plotting functions change, then instead of `If[condition, Plot[], Plot[]]`, I would recommend `Plot[If[condition, expression1, expression2], repeataedIdenticalOptions]`.

In other words, change your `If[....]` to:

```
Plot[
  If[comp === {}, fun[func, t]/scale[func], comp/scale[func]], 
  {t, 0, 9*Gyr}, 
  FrameTicks -> fRDticks, 
  Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, InfiniteLine[{{0, Roche[ρ]}, {10, Roche[ρ]}}]}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness[0.01]]
]
```